# Удаление элементов массива B, идущих подряд в массиве A

Tags: f#

Нужно удалить элементы массива B, идущие подряд в массиве A.
Мне удалось дойти умом до контрольной точки в виде просто удаления элементов массива B из A.

Код:

```
let A = [|1;2;3;4;5|]

let B = [|1;2;0;4;5|]

let C = [|1;2;5;6;7|]

let isContains digit array = 
    array|> Array.tryFind(fun elem -> if elem = digit then true else false)

let InteractArr (array:int[]) =
    array|>Array.filter(fun elem -> (isContains elem A).IsSome) |> Array.distinct

let Interact = InteractArr B//результат - 1, 2, 4, 5

//удаление элементов из Interact, которые совпадают с C.

let DeletNumArr (array:int[]) =
   array|>Array.filter(fun elem -> (isContains elem C).IsNone) |> Array.distinct

let Resultate = DeletNumArr Interact//результат - 4, а нужно, чтобы выводило 4, 5, т.к. подряд идут только 1 и 2.
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что означает "идущие подряд"? Если у нас массив A такого вида: [1;2;3;5;7;8;9], то какие числа нужно удалить из B? И если, например, в массиве B несколько одинаковых элементов, равных числу, которое нужно удалить, то нужно удалить их все?

Comment: Ну смотрите. Есть множество A вида [1;2;5;6;7;4] и есть множество B вида [2,4,5,6]. Во множестве A присутствуют элементы из B. Нужно удалить те из них, которые подряд идут, т.е. есть 2,5,6 , которые идут подряд и их надо удалить, а есть еще и 4, но оно не идет следующим после 6, поэтому удалять не нужно.